# How do I manually invoke an Action in swing?

Tags: java, swing, action

For the life of me I cannot seem to find details on Java Swing Actions :'( When I came across them I immediately realised their usefulness. So far it's all been easy to work with. Now I'm stuck with one little thing: How do I run them manually? I mean by code? Note that I am building the GUI using Netbeans (if that makes any difference). I've come as far as:

```
Application a = Application.getInstance(JPADemoApp.class);
ApplicationContext ctx = a.getContext();
ActionMap am = ctx.getActionMap(JPADemoView.class, this.app);
Action act = am.get("fetchOrders");
```

( I wrote all on separate lines to simplify debugging )

So now I have a valid reference to the Action. Now how do I run it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to run your action manually, you can generate an `ActionEvent` and pass it into the `actionPerformed` method that your `Action` must implement, as the `Action` interface extends `ActionListener`.

Comment: I came across this question again, and your answer is - in my opinion - more detailed than the one of @b1nary.atr0phy. Even though it has more upvotes, I will keep this one accepted. I guess the other one attracts more votes as it is copy/pasteable. Maybe a code-sample would improve this answer?

Comment: Definitely, a code sample would be handy - not to support copy / paste programming, but it would illustrate the concept in a manner more understandable to a programmer.

Comment: ActionEvent does not construct with an Action

Answer (score 38):

You can simply invoke the action event's method directly:

```
for(ActionListener a: buttonExample.getActionListeners()) {
    a.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(this, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, null) {
          //Nothing need go here, the actionPerformed method (with the
          //above arguments) will trigger the respective listener
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because an [`Action`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html) is an [`EventListener`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EventListener.html), you may want to consider implementing an [`EventListenerList`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html) as a way to expose methods that fire actions.