# How to press Enter key using Java?

Tags: java, enter

I want to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> Key when a new window pop up for example for downloading a file. I have to press OK button.

So I tried the following code:

```
Robot r = new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

This is just ignoring. Do you have any idea.
Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630194/java-ignores-vk-enter-event-generated-by-robot

Comment: Do you want to simulate an 'Enter' Key press, or do you want to do something when the user physically presses 'Enter'?

Comment: I want to simulate an "Enter" Key press.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079524/how-do-i-manually-invoke-an-action-in-swing

Comment: For which purpose? Depending on that the solution may vary. Do you want to send an `Enter`-key event to the OS such that the application which has currently focus can use it, for example to create a new line in the text editor that currently has focus? Or do you want to press some buttons in your **Java swing application** or stuff like that? Is the key-event supposed to leave your application (getting send to the OS)?

Comment: I think anubian already answered in his comment. this seems to be a copied/duplicate question. And yes question is also incomplete.

Comment: If you want to use Robot, you first need to (somehow) set the focus on the OK button before you actually press Enter. Didn't use robot for a while so I don't know how of the top of my head

Answer (score -1):

This code simulates pressing the Enter Key:

```
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    keyboard.nextLine();
```

Comment: Depending on the application of OP this answer is not necessarily correct. Your code sends a *new-line* command to the channel connected to the Java application via `System.in`. That could be a **console** like Windows *cmd* or nobody in case of **javaw**. It does not emulate pressing the *Enter*-key on the keyboard. For example to create a new line in a text editor that currently has focus by the OS.